# Searching non-leftmost values with VLOOKUP-like function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question about excel function.

The question is:

> I want to use VLOOKUP-like function, but VLOOKUP only search leftmost row. 
>   Is there any function that searches non-leftmost row (you can select) and the behavior is almost same as VLOOKUP function?

If you don't understand, please see this picture.
I want to do like this in Excel.

[image: Example]

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### INDEX MATCH Combo

You can use combination of 2 functions:
[`INDEX` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)

> The INDEX function returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or range.

[`MATCH` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

> The MATCH function searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range. For example, if the range A1:A3 contains the values 5, 25, and 38, then the formula =MATCH(25,A1:A3,0) returns the number 2, because 25 is the second item in the range.

### Example

`=INDEX(Name_col, MATCH(Rank_input, Rank_col, 0))`.

Equivalent, using your concrete data, assuming you have "Alex" in A3:
`=INDEX($A$3:$A$7, MATCH(A10, $C$3:$C$7, 0))`

Comment: Solved. Thank you :-)